# clean approach to decorator that takes optional keyword arguments

Tags: python, meta-programming

I write decorators a lot in my work. Sometimes you need to write "decorator that takes arguments", it usually turns out to be something like this:

```
def decorator(**kwargs):

    def _decorator(func):

        @wraps(func)
        def decorated(*func_args, **func_kwargs):
            # do something with kwargs here
            return func(*func_args, **func_kwargs)

        return decorated

    return _decorator
```

but in this case you'll always have to use your decorator like so:

```
@decorator()  # if you forget () here you'll get an exception
def myfunc():
    pass
```

So I come up with this snippet, IMO this is nicer to read/write and understand:

```
from functools import wraps, partial

def decorator(func=None, **kwargs):
    if func:

        @wraps(func)
        def decorated(*func_args, **func_kwargs):

            if kwargs.get("sayhi"):
                print("hi")

            return func(*func_args, **func_kwargs)

        return decorated

    else:
        return partial(decorator, **kwargs)

@decorator
def hello(name):
    print(f"hello {name}")


@decorator(sayhi=True)
def bye(name):
    print(f"bye {name}")

hello("rabbit")
# "hello rabbit"

bye("rabbit")
# hi
# bye rabbit
```

Comment: Code Review requires real code. Do you have a concrete use case that is not a toy example, so that we can give you proper advice?

Comment: I agree with @200_success. This is borderline-hypothetical code; have a read through https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1981/the-gray-areas-of-code-review-hypothetical-example-code

Comment: hmmm it isn't really a question i just want to share this with people, where should i post it?

Comment: @rabbit.aaron Github.

Comment: I disagree, this is working code. though the real logic isn't displayed inside the code, it serves as a template for myself to write decorators. The purpose of the code is clearly stated in my post. I do think this question complies with most of the things mentioned in the guideline here. https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1954/checklist-for-how-to-write-a-good-code-review-question . if the code isn't working i would have posted it on stackoverflow.

Comment: Greetings! I voted to close (we can always re-open later) because the code is too obviously not the real code, it is stub code. There is little (not enough) value in reviewing stub code, so we don't do that here.

Comment: @rabbit.aaron, where can you plug this into real production code?  do you have to change anything in order to use it in "the wild"?

Answer (score 3):

Nice little snippet! A couple of minor points:

- It's usually better to put the shorter block first in an `if` `else`. This stops the `else` statement being far from the `if`, making it clearer how the logic flows.
- When comparing to `None`, check `if func is None` or similar, rather than comparing to `True`/`False`.
- Although this is just a toy example, docstrings should always be used to show what the code does and returns.
- PEP8 spacing between imports, functions and code.
- Argument names could be better but without knowing the application it's hard to say what they should be.

```py
from functools import partial, wraps


def decorator(func=None, **kwargs):
    """
    Decorator which optionally takes an argument sayhi (True or False).
    prints 'hi' if True, function is then returned as normal
    """
    if func is None:
        return partial(decorator, **kwargs)
    else:
        @wraps(func)
        def decorated(*func_args, **func_kwargs):
            if kwargs.get('sayhi'):
                print('hi')
            return func(*func_args, **func_kwargs)
        return decorated
```